# Change SharePoint 2013 Service Account

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, service, service-account

- I have SharePoint 2013 post installed with a single account which runs all SharePoint services.
- Now I want to apply the best practice [SharePoint 2013: Service Accounts](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/14500.sharepoint-2013-service-accounts.aspx) on the SharePoint server by using a different user for each service.

Comment: please provide a clear details for your question

Comment: @A.Saéed *edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is healthy practice to use separate accounts for services. As you mentioned you are running the farm with single account and we treat it as a Farm admin account which will run Central admin app pool, SharePoint timer service, Application discovery and load balancer service etc.

For changing the service accounts, I would follow these steps.

- create new service account in AD
- register those accounts inside the SharePoint as Managed Accounts.
- set the permission on the Config db as well as other related services or content databases.
- Now you can change the most of the services account i.e App pools, Service application etc from central admin. central admin > security > configure service accounts. select the service from 1st drop down then select the account from 2nd drop down. [this is the guide](http://www.boostsolutions.com/blog/how-to-configure-service-account-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Also check this guide to change the service accounts: [Service Accounts and Managed Service Accounts in SharePoint 2010](http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/2010/10/service-accounts-and-managed-service-accounts-in-sharepoint-2010/)